# Single Page Application with different pages(html) files loading on scroll and change url accordingly

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, single-page-application, history.js

I want to create a Single Page application which has following features:

- Url changes with scroll to each section
- Each section has it's own html file (for the SEO purposes)
- Scroll to and fro between sections
- When user directly goes to a link e.g www.mysite.com/biography

  - It should scroll to that part of page and still have the ability to scroll up 
    and down to other sections. I mean `view source` shows the html of that 'biography.html' file.

I have created it this far that it changes the url and loads the next html file contents at the end of page when scroll reaches but I don't understand how to load previous contents when I go directly to a page like mysite.com/page3. So scrolling down will get me page#4 and page#5 but how can I scroll upto page#2 and page#1.

I am fairly new to Front end development. Please some help and sample code for direction will be much appreciated.

I am looking for something like this site: https://theoffshorepartners.com/

Comment: Your question is way to general. If you are fairly new to front-end development then you shouldn't be creating SPAs...you should be learning instead...do you have any more specific question?

Comment: Did you even try to this by your self friend. I don't think you will get much help asking for a code base with out showing your commitments. It's best if you can show any code you are working on.

Comment: Yes, I have created it so far that it changes the url and loads the content of the new page on the scroll. I have used keep-scrolling.js and HTML history API. I can give you the code base via email.